# Using a Flash CS4 asset in Flash Builder AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-builder

I have written a flash cs4 custom button class in actionscript 3 with its unique look-and-feel and transitions on up/down etc events. How can I import the Flash assets and use it Flash Builder for an AIR application?

Answer (score 1):

Export your flash cs4 document as a swc that you can then add to your Library path in your FlashBuilder project, but before doing so, you should consider linking your button to an external class which would be accessible in FlashBuilder.